# How to check if user has a token on a DIFFERENT blockchain?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-20, nft, cross-chain

I would like to check if the user, that is calling a Solidity smart contract function, has a specific token (erc20, erc721, or whichever...) on a different blockchain.

*Example:*
Let's say the user is interacting with a smart contract on ethereum in which I would like to check if he owns a specific token on let's say Avalanch or BSC.

Currently I check this in my database and then when user clicks a button I execute a specific smart contract function depending on whether he owns a token on a different chain or not. But this isn't decentralized enough for me...

Any ideas?

Thank you **<3**

Comment: Smart contracts cannot call APIs, but you can try to use an Oracle.

Comment: @JoãoPauloMorais Thanks for your answer. That's what I was thinking as well... I know Chainlink has Cross-Chain Interoperability Protocol (CCIP), but as far as I can tell this hasn't been released yet. And after Googling for a while I haven't found any Oracle that would actually be cross-chain. Do you maybe know of any?